# ADFS Active Redirect with ASP.Net MVC Web API + Javascript\AngularJS does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, claims-based-identity, adfs

Our application supports Single sign on with ADFS.
The application is AngularJS on top of ASP.Net MVC Web API.
Now I've configured the Application as A relying party in the ADFS and pointed the issuer to the ADFS site in the application web.Config as the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="loggerDefinitions" type="System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </configSections>
  <loggerDefinitions>
    <add key="ConsoleLogger" value="true" />
    <add key="FileLogger" value="true" />
  </loggerDefinitions>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="TranslationFilesPath" value="~/Content/translations/" />
    <add key="CannedPhrasesFilePath" value="~/Content/CannedPhrases.xml" />
    <add key="CommunicatorPresenceFilePath" value="~/Content/CommunicatorPresence.xml" />
    <add key="GadgetConfigurationPath" value="GadgetoryConfig.xml" />
    <add key="GenericGadgetIcon" value="~/content/images/generic.png" />
    <!--Logging parameters-->
    <add key="Trace Level" value="7"/>
    <add key="Enable Syslog" value="1"/>
    <add key="Syslog Host" value="localhost"/>
    <add key="Syslog Port" value="514"/>
    <add key="Syslog Trace Level" value="7"/>
    <add key="Enable Debug Log" value="1"/>
    <!--ConfigCom log parameter-->
    <add key="ConfigComDebugOptions" value="1" />
    <add key="ConfigComDebugLevel" value="7" />
    <!--ConfigCom login parameter-->
    <add key="ApplicationId" value="%ServerInstanceId%"/>
    <add key="IPAddress" value="%AISIPAddress%"/>
    <add key="AISPort" value="%AISPort%"/>
  </appSettings>
  <location path="FederationMetadata">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationMode="4.5" />
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="FixedWSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="Enghouse.Gadgetory.Web.Models.FixedWSFederationAuthenticationModule, Enghouse.Gadgetory.Web" />
      <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="FixedWSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="Enghouse.Gadgetory.Web.Models.FixedWSFederationAuthenticationModule, Enghouse.Gadgetory.Web" />
      <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <audienceUris>
        <add value="https://ccsp12.PJ12.LOC/touchpointadfs#/Login" />
        <add value="https://ccsp12.PJ12.LOC/touchpointadfs" />
      </audienceUris>
      <!-- The certificateValidationMode="None" setting is insecure and used only to ease running this sample application. This setting should not be used in production deployments. -->
      <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
      <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <trustedIssuers>
          <add thumbprint="askjfhaskjlfhasdjklhfkljashfkdjhaskdj" name="http://sts.pj12.loc/adfs/services/trust" />
        </trustedIssuers>
      </issuerNameRegistry>
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>
  <system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
      <wsFederation issuer="https://sts.pj12.loc/adfs/ls/" realm="https://ccsp12.PJ12.LOC/touchpointadfs/" requireHttps="false" passiveRedirectEnabled="false" />
      <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />
    </federationConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel.services>
</configuration>
```

You can notice that **passiveRedirectEnabled** is set to **false** and that **allow users** is set to *
The reason is we want to control the when the redirect of the application to ADFS will happen.

I've created a service that calls an MVC function from angularJS code as the following:

```
angular.module('app.utils').factory('adfsLoginService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
    return new function () {
        var self = this;

        var claims = [];

        self.login = function () {
            var url = window.constants.rootPath + "ADFSLogin/Login/";
            return $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: url
            })
            .then(function (data) {
                alert(data.data);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                alert(error.data);
                return $q.reject(error)
            });
        };
    }
}]);
```

MVC function:

```
public ActionResult Login()
        {
            // Redirect user to identity provider STS for obtaining a token using WS-Federation Passive Protocol.
            FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SignIn("LoginPageSignInSubmit");
            return new EmptyResult();
        }
```

For some reason, **instead of redirecting to ADFS sts login page, it returns a string with the url.**
With passiveRedirectEnabled=true it redirects at the start of the application and everything is working fine.

Why the redirection is not working when calling it from $http request ?
Thanks !

Comment: what is the value of data.status and data.headers in angular?  I am guessing this is "expected" because the .SignIn method just issues an Http Redirect (302) with the location in the body of the response.